# Error with testing a template with boost::test

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-test

I'm trying to test a little buffer template with `boost::test`.

This is my template.

```
template <size_t N, EndianType endianType = EndianType::NativeEndianType>
class Buffer {
public:

  Buffer();
  template <typename T>
  Buffer(T* data);
  template <typename T>
  Buffer(T* data, size_t maxSize);
  Buffer(const Buffer&) = default;
  Buffer(Buffer&&) = default;
  ~Buffer() = default;

  template <typename T>
  void setValue(const T& data, size_t byteIndex);

  template<typename T, size_t Index>
  void setValue(const T& data);

  template <typename T>
  T getValue(size_t byteIndex) const noexcept;

  template <typename T, size_t Index>
  T getValue() const noexcept;



public:

  Buffer& operator=(const Buffer&) = default;
  Buffer& operator=(Buffer&&) = default;

private:

  using ByteArray = std::array<std::byte, N>;

private:

  ByteArray m_data;
};


template <size_t N, EndianType endianType>
Buffer<N, endianType>::Buffer() {
  memset(m_data.data(), 0, N);
}

template <size_t N, EndianType endianType>
template <typename T>
Buffer<N, endianType>::Buffer(T* data) {
  memcpy(m_data.data(), data, N);
}

template <size_t N, EndianType endianType>
template <typename T>
Buffer<N, endianType>::Buffer(T* data, size_t maxSize) {
  memset(m_data.data(), 0, N);
  memcpy(m_data.data(), data, std::min(maxSize, N));
}

template <size_t N, EndianType endianType>
template <typename T>
void Buffer<N, endianType>::setValue(const T& data, size_t byteIndex) {
  memcpy(m_data.data() + byteIndex, &data, sizeof(data));
}

template <size_t N, EndianType endianType>
template <typename T, size_t Index>
void Buffer<N, endianType>::setValue(const T& data) {
  static_assert(Index < N - sizeof(T), "Cannot read data: can go in overflow");
  memcpy(m_data.data() + Index, &data, sizeof(data));
}

template <size_t N, EndianType endianType>
template <typename T>
T Buffer<N, endianType>::getValue(size_t byteIndex) const noexcept {
  return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(m_data.data() + byteIndex);
}

template <size_t N, EndianType endianType>
template <typename T, size_t Index>
T Buffer<N, endianType>::getValue() const noexcept {
  static_assert(Index < N - sizeof(T), "Cannot read data: can go in overflow");
  return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(m_data.data() + Index);
}
```

The idea to set/get a value in the buffer is to have two methods for them: one that set the index as method parameter (i.e. if you need to calculate the index at runtime), and one that use the index as template parameter (for using `static_assert` for example).

This is my test case file:

```
#include "stdafx.hpp"
#include "XXX/Buffer.hpp"


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(BufferTest);

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(BufferConstructor) {
  constexpr auto data{ "string" };
  Buffer<6> buffer(data);
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(0), 's');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(1), 't');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(2), 'r');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(3), 'i');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(4), 'n');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(5), 'g');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char, 0>(), 's');
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END();
```

In the test case I've some errors in the last row (I'm using Visual Studio 2022):

```
>------ Build All started: Project: wcigi, Configuration: debug-Debug ------
  [1/2] Building CXX object tests\WCIGI\CMakeFiles\WCIGITest.dir\BufferTest.cpp.obj
  FAILED: tests/WCIGI/CMakeFiles/WCIGITest.dir/BufferTest.cpp.obj 
  C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1436~1.325\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP  -IP:\Projects\wcigi\tests\WCIGI\..\..\src -IP:\Projects\wcigi\build\debug\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include -IP:\Projects\wcigi\tests\WCIGI /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -std:c++20 /showIncludes /Fotests\WCIGI\CMakeFiles\WCIGITest.dir\BufferTest.cpp.obj /Fdtests\WCIGI\CMakeFiles\WCIGITest.dir\ /FS -c P:\Projects\wcigi\tests\WCIGI\BufferTest.cpp
P:\Projects\wcigi\tests\WCIGI\BufferTest.cpp(16): warning C4002: too many arguments for function-like macro invocation 'BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL'
P:\Projects\wcigi\tests\WCIGI\BufferTest.cpp(16): error C2672: 'WCIGI::Buffer<6,WCIGI::EndianType::Little>::getValue': no matching overloaded function found
  P:\Projects\wcigi\src\WCIGI/Buffer.hpp(33): note: could be 'T WCIGI::Buffer<6,WCIGI::EndianType::Little>::getValue(void) noexcept const'
  P:\Projects\wcigi\tests\WCIGI\BufferTest.cpp(16): note: 'WCIGI::Buffer<6,WCIGI::EndianType::Little>::getValue': too many template arguments
  P:\Projects\wcigi\src\WCIGI/Buffer.hpp(30): note: or       'T WCIGI::Buffer<6,WCIGI::EndianType::Little>::getValue(size_t) noexcept const'
  P:\Projects\wcigi\tests\WCIGI\BufferTest.cpp(16): note: 'WCIGI::Buffer<6,WCIGI::EndianType::Little>::getValue': too many template arguments
P:\Projects\wcigi\tests\WCIGI\BufferTest.cpp(16): error C2672: 'boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_frwd': no matching overloaded function found
  P:\Projects\wcigi\build\debug\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\boost/test/tools/old/impl.hpp(92): note: could be 'bool boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_frwd(Pred,const boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream &,boost::unit_test::const_string,size_t,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type,const Arg0 &,const char *,const Arg1 &,const char *,const Arg2 &,const char *,const Arg3 &,const char *,const Arg4 &,const char *)'
  P:\Projects\wcigi\tests\WCIGI\BufferTest.cpp(16): note: 'bool boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_frwd(Pred,const boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream &,boost::unit_test::const_string,size_t,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type,const Arg0 &,const char *,const Arg1 &,const char *,const Arg2 &,const char *,const Arg3 &,const char *,const Arg4 &,const char *)': expects 16 arguments - 7 provided
  P:\Projects\wcigi\build\debug\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\boost/test/tools/old/impl.hpp(92): note: or       'bool boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_frwd(Pred,const boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream &,boost::unit_test::const_string,size_t,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type,const Arg0 &,const char *,const Arg1 &,const char *,const Arg2 &,const char *,const Arg3 &,const char *)'
  P:\Projects\wcigi\tests\WCIGI\BufferTest.cpp(16): note: 'bool boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_frwd(Pred,const boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream &,boost::unit_test::const_string,size_t,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type,const Arg0 &,const char *,const Arg1 &,const char *,const Arg2 &,const char *,const Arg3 &,const char *)': expects 14 arguments - 7 provided
  P:\Projects\wcigi\build\debug\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\boost/test/tools/old/impl.hpp(92): note: or       'bool boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_frwd(Pred,const boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream &,boost::unit_test::const_string,size_t,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type,const Arg0 &,const char *,const Arg1 &,const char *,const Arg2 &,const char *)'
  P:\Projects\wcigi\tests\WCIGI\BufferTest.cpp(16): note: 'bool boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_frwd(Pred,const boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream &,boost::unit_test::const_string,size_t,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type,const Arg0 &,const char *,const Arg1 &,const char *,const Arg2 &,const char *)': expects 12 arguments - 7 provided
  P:\Projects\wcigi\build\debug\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\boost/test/tools/old/impl.hpp(92): note: or       'bool boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_frwd(Pred,const boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream &,boost::unit_test::const_string,size_t,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type,const Arg0 &,const char *,const Arg1 &,const char *)'
  P:\Projects\wcigi\tests\WCIGI\BufferTest.cpp(16): note: 'bool boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_frwd(Pred,const boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream &,boost::unit_test::const_string,size_t,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type,const Arg0 &,const char *,const Arg1 &,const char *)': expects 10 arguments - 7 provided
  P:\Projects\wcigi\build\debug\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\boost/test/tools/old/impl.hpp(92): note: or       'bool boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_frwd(Pred,const boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream &,boost::unit_test::const_string,size_t,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type,const Arg0 &,const char *)'
  P:\Projects\wcigi\tests\WCIGI\BufferTest.cpp(16): note: 'bool boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_frwd(Pred,const boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream &,boost::unit_test::const_string,size_t,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level,boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type,const Arg0 &,const char *)': expects 8 arguments - 7 provided
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Build All failed.
```

I'm not sure that the problem is my code, because if I write the test in the following way, it compiles and runs correctly:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(BufferConstructor) {
  constexpr auto data{ "string" };
  Buffer<6> buffer(data);
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(0), 's');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(1), 't');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(2), 'r');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(3), 'i');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(4), 'n');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(5), 'g');
  auto x = buffer.getValue<char, 0>();
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(x, 's');
}
```

Or even this way:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(BufferConstructor) {
  constexpr auto data{ "string" };
  Buffer<6> buffer(data);
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(0), 's');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(1), 't');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(2), 'r');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(3), 'i');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(4), 'n');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(buffer.getValue<char>(5), 'g');
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL((buffer.getValue<char, 0>()), 's'); // Look at extra parenthesis
}
```

So I don't know if the error is related to my code or if it's specific to `boost::test`, because I cannot see any difference in the logic of the boost macro between the row with the error and other ones.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the problem is with macros being greedy about `,`. "it compiles and runs correctly:" looks fine, just do it.